# accessing many to many data in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two models, one referencing the other in a many to many relationship (the BannerProject object may contain multiple instances of the BannerEntry object):

```
class BannerEntry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    has_static = models.BooleanField()
    has_flash = models.BooleanField()
    static_preview = models.FileField(upload_to=content_banner_page, blank=True, null=True, max_length=300)
    static_zip = models.FileField(upload_to=content_banner_page, blank=True, null=True, max_length=300)
    ...

class BannerProject(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    parent_page = models.ForeignKey(BannerPage, blank=True, null=True)
    banner_entry = models.ManyToManyField(BannerEntry)

    def __unicode__ (self):
            return u'%s %s' % (self.client, self.project_name)

    class Admin: 
            pass
```

running through a basic view function:

```
def display_bannerpage(request, client):
    records = BannerPage.objects.filter(client=client)
    bprjrecords = BannerProject.objects.filter(client=client)
    tpl = 'clientportal_tmps/bannerpage.html'
    return render_to_response(tpl, { 'records': records, 'bprjrecords': bprjrecords })
```

and I want to display them in a template (BannerProject, child Entry1 fields, childEntry2 fields, child Entry3 fields… Next BannerProject, etc…):
my current template looks something like:

```
{% if bprjrecords %}
{% for bprjrecord in bprjrecords %}

{% for banner_entry in bprjrecord %}
{{ banner_entry.title }}
{{ banner_entry.static_preview }}
{{ banner_entry.static_zip }}
{% endfor %}
```

which throws a TypeError "'BannerProject' object is not iterable"

what is the correct template language that will allow me to access the BannerEntry data so that I can display it in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over the BannerProject, and not the BannerEntry list for that project. Try this:

```
{% for banner_entry in bprjrecord.banner_entry.all %}
    {{ banner_entry.title }}
    {{ banner_entry.static_preview }}
    {{ banner_entry.static_zip }}
{% endfor %}
```